# Как в Jenkins настроить выполнение шага сборки, по проверке изменения файла в директории

Tags: jenkins

Хочу настроить выполнение скрипта, в том случае если определенный файл в директории был модифицирован (например дата изменения файла скорректировалась),
где-то промелькивала такая настройка, но вот в каком плагине?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, нужен плагин
https://plugins.jenkins.io/fstrigger

(Есть много решений, основанных на работе с git, но файлик который я мониторю не лежит в гите, поэтому все остальные подходы для меня не сработали)